# I want to remove all non-digits and all punctuations except "."

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I want to remove all non-digit symbols and punctuations except ".". I have done similar job to remove all non-digit symbols like this:

```
 if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(this.value)) {
     this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/, "");
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks for helping.

Comment: You could match not a digit or a dot using `[^\d.]+` and repeat it 1+ times. Then replace with an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\D` will match any character that is not a digit.

If you also don't want to match a dot, you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\d.]+` which will match any character except a dot or a digit.

As you are replacing it with an empty string, you could repeat the character class 1+ times.

Use the `/g` global flag to replace all occurrences.

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d.]+/g, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
```